# Created exe from .py using pyinstaller has issues with tensorflow path

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pyinstaller

Using pyinstaller I have created an exe from python script.
The script has dependency on tensorflow. The package is created perfectly. 
The issue is when I run the exe.

Python 3.6.5
Pyinstaller 3.3.1
Build platform : Win 8.1 64bit
Running platform Win 7 64bit

---

```
C:\Program Files\test\FaceDetectionPackageBeta1\dist\FaceDetection>FaceDetection.exe
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14,
 in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_inter
nal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <modu
le>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17,
 in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16,
 in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 714, in load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TELFaceDetection.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <modu
le>
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14,
 in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_inter
nal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <modu
le>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17,
 in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16,
 in swig_import_helper
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_
importers.py", line 714, in load_module
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
[4988] Failed to execute script TELFaceDetection
```

---

Below is the spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['FaceDetection.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\FaceDetectionSetup\\FaceDetectioPackageSource'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='FaceDetection',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='FaceDetection')
```

I have tried the solution in  [link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2828#issuecomment-404681720), but that does not work either. when I execute the exe, **No module named tensorflow.python.framework.load_library** error is received.

How do I set the path so that relative path is picked. 
The same worked without any issues on Win 7 64bit desktop system.So working on one system and not on the other.Any help appreciated.

Thanks 
-Megha

Answer (score 0):

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): 
    appPath = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    appPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Using this code you can specify your application directory path variable for executable as well as when running .py directly.